# changing strings used in prompt() function in for loop is not changing displayed prompt

Tags: javascript, function, loops

```
var two = "Ask me something!"

function ask(one, two) {
    if (one == "hi") {
        two = "Hello how are you!"
    } else if (user == "How old are       you?") {
        two = "I am 800 years old"
    }
};

for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
      prompt(two);
      ask()
}
```

I'm trying to be able to keep answering the questions and get them to change every time. But when I run it every prompt says the same thing: "Ask me something." Please help me find my logic error.

Comment: take a look at the answer provided and let me know if it works or not. One question is whether this is indeed JavaScript or not.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JavaScript so I am going to work with that. You have a couple of problems with your source code.

First of all, your function `ask()` needs to have some arguments provided when it is called within the loop.

Below I provide a modified example in JavaScript which change the string displayed by `prompt()`.  This uses a global variable, `two` which is modified by the function `ask()` depending on the number specified in the argument. The value of the string of `two` is modified to a new string.

This is using a `switch()` statement and if the value specified is in the range of 1 (one) up to and including 10 (ten), the value of `two` is changed to the new string specified. If the value specified in the argument to `ask()` is not in range then the value of `two` is not changed.

You can modify the `case` statements where the assignment to the global variable `two` is made to change the actual prompts or what is displayed in the `prompt()` box.

For information about the `prompt()` function see this page, [JavaScript Popup Boxes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) which discusses three types of popup windows or boxes including the `prompt()` box.

You probably want something like the following.

```
<script>
// create a global variable we are going to use for our prompts.
// each time the function ask() is called, the variable will be modified.
var two = "Ask me something!"

// the function ask() which takes an argument and changes the global variable
// two to a different string.  the function takes two arguments.
// the first argument is an index value from 1 to 10 inclusive.
// the second argument is a string to append to the selected prompt.
function ask(one,answer) 
{
    switch (one) {
        case 1:
            two = " 1. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 2:
            two = " 2. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 3:
            two = " 3. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 4:
            two = " 4. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 5:
            two = " 5. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 6:
            two = " 6. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 7:
            two = " 7. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 8:
            two = " 8. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 9:
            two = " 9. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
        case 10:
            two = "10. Hello how are you! " + answer;
            break;
    }
};

// run a loop providing a prompt and then changing the global variable two
// to provide a different prompt. we provide a default string, the second
// argument that includes the value of the index variable used in the loop.
//
// we are taking what ever the user enters and appends that string to the
// next prompt string.
//
// if the user presses the Cancel button on the prompt box then we will get
// a value of null and so we will just break out of the loop.
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      var answer = prompt(two, "stuff " + i);
      if (answer == null) break;
      ask(i, answer)
}
</script>
```